# How do I static_assert the type that an iterator dereferences to?

Tags: c++

```
template <typename InputIterator>
MyFun(const InputIterator begin, const InputIterator end)
{
    // I want to static_assert that decltype(*begin) == SomeType
}
```

How can I do this? I'm thinking `static_assert(std::is_same<*InputIterator,SomeType>)` but that of course does not work...

Comment: It's pretty darn rare to want `const InputIterator`s.  You probably want to remove the `const`.

Comment: @MooingDuck I can think of only few situations where you _wouldn't_ want the `const`... Why would you want to modify an iterator passed by value?

Comment: The normal thing to do with an iterator is to... _iterate_.  And you can't iterate a `const` iterator.  Did you forget the distinction between `iterator`, `const_iterator`, `const iterator`, and `const const_iterator`?  Even so, there's a huge number of algorithms that mutate data, which all take mutable iterators to mutable data: copy, move, fill, transform, generate, remove, replace, swap, reverse, rotate, shuffle, unique, partition, sort, merge, make_heap, pop_heap, push_heap, sort_heap...

Comment: @MooingDuck `for(auto i : iterator_range(begin, end)`; that's 90% of use cases. `begin` and `end` can be `const`.

Comment: Incorrect.  About 60% of the time, `begin()` is called on a `const` objects, and returns a non-const `const_iterator`.  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/begin says "`iterator begin(); const_iterator begin() const;`"  Note that _neither one_ returns a `const iterator`.

Comment: @MooingDuck there is no reason to ever return an object by const value. Iterators are no exception. This has nothing to do with what we were talking about.

Comment: In the context of `iterator_range(begin,end)` I figured those should be `begin()` and `end()`, in which case it's related. If I mis-guessed there, my bad.  Alright, the other end then: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm There's roughly one hundred standard algorithms implemented here, plus unlisted overloads.  Exactly 0% of them take a `const SomethingIterator`.

Comment: @MooingDuck That's true, my guess is that it's either a style preference on the part of the committee or that it allows the implementation to perform micro optimizations. E.g. you might find that `for(; begin != end; ++begin)` is faster than a range based loop when compiler optimizations are disabled or on certain compilers. In that case you would need `begin` to be non const.

Comment: Well, also there's no reason for it to be `const` in the first place.  It's the function's copy of the iterator, it should be able to do whatever it wants with it.  If it was a _reference_ I'd definitely expect to see `const`, but never for any function taking a parameter by value.

Comment: @MooingDuck I'd say its not _necessary_ for it to be `const`. Whether or not you make it `const` is a matter of preference. My view is that it adds clarity to the code because it tells the reader of the function that the code won't be modified, but there are differing opinions on this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[std::iterator_traits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits):

```
static_assert(is_same<typename std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::value_type, 
               SomeType>::value, "");
```

Answer (score 3):

An alternative using `decltype`, with a note in passing that it often produces a reference (but may not!).

```
// If you want to assert that the dereferenced item is indeed a reference
static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(*begin), SomeType&>::value, "");

// If you are only interested in the "bare" type
// (equivalent to Jesse's providing iterator_traits was properly specialized)
static_assert(std::is_same<
    typename std::remove_reference<decltype(*begin)>::type,
    SomeType
>::value, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use `std::is_convertible` instead of `std::is_same` and `const SomeType&` instead of `SomeType` because usually, the convertibility to `const SomeType&` is all we need from the iterator.

```
    static_assert(
        std::is_convertible<decltype(*begin), const SomeType&>::value,
        "Input parameters must be iterators over objects convertible to 'SomeType'."
    );
```

In addition, `const SomeType&` shall be changed to `SomeType&` if the data is going to be modified through the iterators. This is essentially useful in case of inheritance where iterators over child objects are passed to a function receiving iterators of parent class.

Here is a concrete example:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>


struct Animal {
    int x;

    inline void print() const {
        std::cout << "x = " << x << std::endl;
    }

    inline int modify() {
        return ++x;
    }

    virtual ~Animal() = default;
};

struct Cat: public Animal {
};

struct Dog: public Animal {
};


template<typename I>
inline void printAnimals(I begin, I end) {
    static_assert(
        std::is_convertible<decltype(*begin), const Animal&>::value,
        "Input parameters must be iterators over objects of type 'Animal'."
    );
    for (I it = begin; it != end; ++it) {
        const Animal& a = *it;
        a.print();
    }
    std::cout << "---------" << std::endl;
}


template<typename I>
inline void modifyAnimals(I begin, I end) {
    static_assert(
        std::is_convertible<decltype(*begin), Animal&>::value,
        "Input parameters must be iterators over objects of type 'Animal'."
    );
    for (I it = begin; it != end; ++it) {
        Animal& a = *it;
        a.modify();
    }
}

int main() {
    std::vector<Dog> dogs(2);
    dogs[0].x = 10;
    dogs[1].x = 20;
    printAnimals(dogs.begin(), dogs.end());
    modifyAnimals(dogs.begin(), dogs.end());
    printAnimals(dogs.begin(), dogs.end());

    std::vector<Cat> cats(3);
    cats[0].x = 100;
    cats[1].x = 110;
    cats[2].x = 120;
    printAnimals(cats.begin(), cats.end());
    modifyAnimals(cats.begin(), cats.end());
    printAnimals(cats.begin(), cats.end());
    return 0;
}
```