# Enforce template function parameters to be iterators on a specific type

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, iterator, typechecking

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24776520/cast-lista-to-listb-where-b-inherits-a)

I got a function template

```
template <typename T1, typename T2, typename IT1, typename IT2>
MethodResult<T1, T2>& method (IT1 it1begin, IT1 it1end, IT2 it2begin, IT2 it2end);
```

With the following inheritance scheme

```
class A
class B : A
class C : A
```

I would like the function to enforce 
`IT1` and `IT2` to be iterator which dereference to `T1` and `T2` respectively.

To do so I tried

```
static_assert(std::is_base_of< A, 
                               typename list<T1>::iterator::value_type >::value,
                               "wrong type");
```

Which compiles fine, however it doesn't enforce anything as when I call

```
method<B, C>("not an", "iterator", 3, 2);
```

The compiler doesn't yields an error.

Please note that I tried first

```
        static_assert(std::is_base_of<A, 
                                      typename std::iterator_traits<T1>::value_type, 
                                      "wrong type");
```

after I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19373490/how-do-i-static-assert-the-type-that-an-iterator-dereferences-to) but the compilers yields.

```
wrong number of template arguments (3, should be 2)
```

Any idea on how to achieve this type-checking ?

Comment: This doesn't make sense. You don't use `IT1` or `IT2` in the code snippets with `static_assert`. In the second snippet, the angle brackets don't match.

Comment: Further fuel to the end, the "when I call" sample has *two* formal parameters being passed; the implementation mandates *four*. None of this makes sense.

Comment: @WhozCraig only 2 of 4 are implicit, only the return types are required for the call as the compiler knows the parameters types.

Comment: @FloW maybe I wasn't clear enough. `method<B, C>("not an iterator", 3);` is being passed *two* parameters (the char array and the `int`). Your prototype has an arg list of `(IT1 it1begin, IT1 it1end, IT2 it2begin, IT2 it2end);` *four* parameters. I didn't say *template parameters*.

Comment: Okay I get what you mean. Just a misleading copy/paste from previous code where method only took 2 parameters. I'm correcting it for the sake of clarity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question is little vague and has a few issues. But I think I get the gist of it. The `static_assert` you are looking for probably;

```
static_assert(std::is_base_of<A,
  typename std::iterator_traits<IT1>::value_type>::value,
  "wrong type");
```

You were missing a few brackets and `value` etc. I've formatted it similarly to your original post.

Comment: My bad for the bracket ... totally missed it and the compiler's message shall have pointed my attention to it.
BTW I think I misunderstood the usage of iterator_traits, now it's clearer. Thanks :)

Comment: @FloW. Template error messages are **notorious** for being misleading about what the actual error is.